# How to Limit Lifecycle Events in Polymer

Tags: polymer, lifecycle, debouncing

I am using the Polymer `shop-app` kit and am trying to run AJAX calls based on lifecycle events.  When running the `connectedCallback` function from the `shop-app` shell "ready" logs out 7 times.

How can I get this to run once instead?

```
connectedCallback() {
  console.log('ready');
}
```

Comment: As your application grows this will become more and more complex, but one idea would be to set a boolean flag, for example `isConnected` to true, and to run your calls in an observer on that flag (since the observer shouldn't fire twice when you set it to true, if it was already true)

Comment: also don't forget that it's normal to fire twice if you have that element twice in the page, as it would fire on two different instances :)